# Why does InDesign reduce the quality of my screenshots when Word doesn't?

Tags: adobe-indesign, resize, screenshot

If I take a screenshot and paste it into InDesign it completely destroys the quality. Yet when I print screen and paste it into Word, the image is resized to the page and the quality is kept. What is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like your display performance is on the low setting.

In your InDesign document, go to the top menu <kbd>View > Display performance</kbd> and choose `High quality display`. The lower settings exists when working with heavy documents, it improves performance. Hope this helps!

Comment: To add on Emilie's point - this is just for display purposes. The low display quality just helps your computer run smoother. The actual quality of the linked image isn't affected, and you could still save it out as a high quality pdf.

Comment: actually there is a difference when you print. Adobes default mode is unsuitable for print of screenshots due to interpolation.